# Compiling PDF from a .rnw file in RStudio gets error in function getSymbols()

Tags: pdf, rstudio, quantmod, sweave, pdflatex

I'm trying to compile a .Rnw file and I am getting errors in the output pdf, the thing is that if I execute in RStudio all the code chunks one by one it works perfectly, but when I try to compile the pdf an error is printed in the output pdf.

```js
## Error in getSymbols("FB", scr = "yahoo", from = "2015-01-01", to = "2015-12-31"): Could not find function getSymbols()
```

In my document, before the chunk where I use the function getSymbols(), i have a `require(quantmod)` that does not gives any error. In fact as I said before if I execute each chunk one by one it works.

Here I let you the outputs of `Sys.which('pdflatex')` and `sessionInfo()` for further Information.

```js
> Sys.which('pdflatex')
           pdflatex 
"/usr/bin/pdflatex"
```

```js
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtable_1.8-2    ggplot2_2.2.1   dplyr_0.7.4     quantmod_0.4-12 TTR_0.23-2      xts_0.10-1     
[7] zoo_1.8-0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14     bindr_0.1        magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 lattice_0.20-35 
 [7] R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.1.6      plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.3      grid_3.4.3       gtable_0.2.0    
[13] lazyeval_0.2.1   assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_1.4.1     bindrcpp_0.2     curl_3.1         glue_1.2.0      
[19] labeling_0.3     compiler_3.4.3   pillar_1.0.1     scales_0.5.0     pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Hope you can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

`require(quantmod)` will return `FALSE` if it can't load `quantmod`, it won't generate an error.  If you want to see an error, use `library(quantmod)`.

The most likely cause of the problem is that RStudio is using a different library of packages than the child session that is processing your document.  You may be able to diagnose this by printing the results of `.libPaths()` in the console in RStudio and in an early chunk of your document, and seeing what the differences are.  `sessionInfo()` in the document will tell you if it is running a different R version.

BTW, this is probably just a typo in your question, but the `getSymbols` argument is `src`, not `scr`.

Comment: I just changed the require(quantmod) by library() and it worked that's a weird thing, maybe the reason is that I tried to work on these project just after installing texlive and some more utils related to the compilation of the pdf, without rebooting the PC